# Zooming image in a scroll view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I want to zoom an image in a scroll view. I used the below code.
All are working fine, but the image is not zooming. Anyone please
help. I am a beginner in iPhone app development.

I had connected the delegate to files manager and set max zooming to 5

I can see the image. But how can I zoom it.

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrForImg;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imgForScr;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImage.png"];
    imgForScr.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];
}


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return imgForScr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html).

HTH.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of Apple's samples demonstrate zooming the way Photos does it, which is definitive. I've filed a radar for this:

http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=204402

Please duplicate if you want the extra functionality of Photos explained.

Answer (score 0):

The image needs to exist in an UIImageView, then you should be able to pan/zoom.

Is it visible? Or does the scroll view contain nothing at all?